# Can't check whether input matches variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to generate a number between 1 and 6 and have the user guess it. The check function, as in `if input == variable:` is not working.

```
global count
count = 0   

 def guess():
        a = random.randint(1,6)
        print (a)
        ffs =input ("whats my nr?")
        if ffs == (a):
            print ("Correct")
            sys.exit()
        else:
            global count
            print ("guess again")
            count +=1
            print ("you have attempts remaining")
    def mainz():
        while count < 6:
            guess()
    mainz()
```

Comment: What would you expect from `'1' == 1`? Python is **strongly** typed.

Comment: so just str(a) got it. Brain fart thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your `mainz()` function and your `mainz()` call are in the `guess()` function but I guess that it's just a formatting error. The real error resides in the fact that input returns a string which you are trying to compare to an int. I would recommend simply doing this:

```
ffs = int(input("What's my nr? ") )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
global count
count = 0
def guess():
    a = random.randint(1,6)
    print (a)
    ffs =input ("whats my nr?")
    if ffs == str(a):
        print ("Correct")
        sys.exit()
    else:
        global count
        print ("guess again")
        count +=1
        print ("you have attempts remaining")
def mainz():
    while count < 6:
        guess()
mainz()
```

Needed str(a)

Comment: You could also use if int(ffs) == a or convert the input to int using int(input("whats my nr?")) or use a = str(random.randint(1, 6))...